# Not this selector on next element in jQuery chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chain

I'm having a chain of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) methods to find a `ul` in a `li` and animate the height of it.

```
$('.collapse-trigger').click(function() { 
    if($(this).next('.collapse-ul').height() == 0) {
        $(this).css('background', '#000000');
        var height = $(this).next('.collapse-ul').children().length; 
        $(this).next('.collapse-ul').animate({height: height*42}, 500); // multiply height with number of menupoints
    }
    else { 
        $(this).css('background', '#414141');
        $(this).next('.collapse-ul').animate({height: 0}, 500);
    }
});
```

with this I can collapse each `ul` and on a click again it animates back to `0`. What I intend to do is, when one of the `ul` is animating out, the others animate back to zero.

I assume I need something like `.not(this)` but struggle with it.
My attempt:

```
$('this').next().not('.collapse-ul', this).animate({height: 0}, 500); // <-- inside the not method I don't know how to write it
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your HTML..?? Or a demo would be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : You can find the collapsible ul first and then filter it using `.not()`

```
$('.collapse-trigger').click(function() { 
    if($(this).next('.collapse-ul').height() == 0) {
        $(this).css('background', '#000000');
        var height = $(this).next('.collapse-ul').children().length;
        var $collapseUl = $(this).next('.collapse-ul');
        //filter current collapsible ul
        $('.collapse-ul').not($collapseUl).animate({height: 0}, 500); 
        $collapseUl.animate({height: height*42}, 500); // multiply height with number of menupoints
    }
    else { 
        $(this).css('background', '#414141');
        $(this).next('.collapse-ul').animate({height: 0}, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, its close, only thing is, that it animates all others to zero but then expands all. Do I miss a blocking variable? edit: nevermind, its working.. :)